# cannot find a jboss-as-jpa jar for hibernate 4.3

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jboss, jboss6.x, jboss-modules

I was upgrading a `hibernate` based project from `4.2.0` to `4.3.2`. The project is deployed in `jboss-eap-6.4` as an `.ear`

The project works with `jboss-as-jpa`. I have defined a persistance.xml in the `.ear` which contains the following property

```xml
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" 
              value="org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform" />
```

(The package location of `JBossAppServerJtaPlatform` has changed from `org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform` to `org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform` while upgrading from hibernate `4.2.0` to `4.3.2`.)

If i start `jboss` it stops almost immediately and the following error appears in the server log.

```
17:40:26,412 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) Failed to define class org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform in Module "org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate:4" from local module loader @757942a1 (finder: local module finder @4a87761d (roots: C:\AlanLal\jboss-eap-6.4\modules,C:\AlanLal\jboss-eap-6.4\modules\system\layers\base)): java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/jboss/as/jpa/hibernate4/JBossAppServerJtaPlatform (Module "org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate:4" from local module loader @757942a1 (finder: local module finder @4a87761d (roots: C:\AlanLal\jboss-eap-6.4\modules,C:\AlanLal\jboss-eap-6.4\modules\system\layers\base)))
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:487) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:277) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:92) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:568) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.HibernatePersistenceProviderAdaptor.injectJtaManager(HibernatePersistenceProviderAdaptor.java:50)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceProviderAdaptorLoader.loadPersistenceAdapterModule(PersistenceProviderAdaptorLoader.java:117) [jboss-as-jpa-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.subsystem.JPAExtension.initialize(JPAExtension.java:110) [jboss-as-jpa-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.extension.ExtensionAddHandler.initializeExtension(ExtensionAddHandler.java:97) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.extension.ParallelExtensionAddHandler$ExtensionInitializeTask.call(ParallelExtensionAddHandler.java:139) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.extension.ParallelExtensionAddHandler$ExtensionInitializeTask.call(ParallelExtensionAddHandler.java:125) [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [rt.jar:1.8.0_172]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [rt.jar:1.8.0_172]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [rt.jar:1.8.0_172]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_172]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/service/jta/platform/internal/JBossAppServerJtaPlatform
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_172]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) [rt.jar:1.8.0_172]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:361) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:482) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform from [Module "org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate:4" from local module loader @757942a1 (finder: local module finder @4a87761d (roots: C:\AlanLal\jboss-eap-6.4\modules,C:\AlanLal\jboss-eap-6.4\modules\system\layers\base))]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    ... 23 more
```

Upon further cause analysis i found a jar in jboss modules folder `jboss-as-jpa-hibernate4-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar`. A class in this jar still extends from org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform (hibernate 4.2.) which is causing the error to come

**Things i tried out**

I tried to a find a newer version of this jar in the [redhat maven repo](https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/org/jboss/as/jboss-as-jpa-hibernate4/), But i couldn't find a suitable compatible version for Hibernate 4.3.0 (even the latest release still refers to `org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform` )

I tried to upgrade to `hibernate 5.` but couldn't find a compatible version of `jboss-as-jpa-hibernate4-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar` in their maven repo.

Is there anywhere else where I could find this jar compatible with `hibernate 4.3.0 or even 5` , or could any other package in the mentioned repo serve the same purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EAP 6.4 supports Hibernate 4.2.18.Final out of the box. Using a different version is imho not recommended and will introduce some troubles. But in general it should be possible according to Hibernate. You will have to patch the server. More infos you can find e.g. here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/topical/html_single/wildfly/Wildfly.html

Beware that you might loose the EAP support from Redhat.

Comment: Hi, I upgraded to jboss eap 7 with hibernate 5 and it worked for me. Thanks for the help :)